# How to use oembed API with soundcloud?

Tags: oembed

I am learning about oembeed,

As i understand, websites such as soundcloud or youtube provide an endpoint like:

```
https://soundcloud.com/oembed
```

then, I could ask soundcloud on that endpoint for a song, playlist etc.. like so:

```
https://soundcloud.com/oembed/giorgiomartini/the-digital-big-bang-wip
```

this is the original link from where i want to get a song:

```
https://soundcloud.com/giorgiomartini/the-digital-big-bang-wip
```

But the eombeed link is not working... im i building the link incorrectly?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I was building the url incorreclty it should be like this:

```
https://soundcloud.com/oembed?format=json&url=https://soundcloud.com/giorgiomartini/the-digital-big-bang-wip
```